# How to check for same value in a loop

Tags: php, mysql, web

My question is: how can I check for the same value while in loop?
I have data collection like this : `1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5`
I want output like this

```
for()
1 no
2 no
3 no
4 yes
5 no
}
```

I have tried like this but not working:

```
 <?php $temp_id = array();?>
for()
if(!in_array($myField,$temp_id)){
no
}else{
yes
}
```

Comment: please write some more about your question.

Comment: hy Deep kakkar my quetions is how I can check same value while in loop

Comment: @b4dQuetions You want to check if a value is more than once in an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this : `$array = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5);`

```
$count = array_count_values($array);
$newArr = array();
foreach ($array as $value) {
  if ($count[$value] > 1) {
    $newArr[$value] = yes;
  }
  else {
    $newArr[$value] = no;
  }
}

print_r($newArr); // produces yes if value is repeated
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_count_values()`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-count-values.php) to do this.

---

To have the return you want you can do the following code

```
foreach (array_count_values($array) as $value => $count) {
    if ($count > 1) {
        echo $value . ' : ' . 'Yes';
    } else {
        echo $value . ' : ' . 'No';
    }
}
```